# WPF binding a nested textbox's text is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a XAML code as follows:

```
<UserControl x:Class="LabsterApp.TestExplorer.TestExplorer"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:TestExplorer="clr-namespace:LabsterApp.TestExplorer" MinHeight="300">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel MinWidth="120">
            <TreeView/>
            <Grid Name="TestInfo">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBox Text="Name:" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=CurrentTestInfo, Path=TestName}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I set the whole control's data context to be its viewmodel (in the code behind):

```
public TestExplorer()
        {
            viewModel = new TreeExplorerViewModel();
            DataContext = viewModel;
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

The viewmodel has a `CurrentTestInfo` object which has a `TestName` property (all public). At some point, I update the `CurrentTestInfo` (creating a new object each time) but the text in the textbox is not updated. I've tried using:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=CurrentTestInfo.TestName}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

instead and also tried a nested binding (textbox\text\binding tags).
The relevant viewmodel part:

```
public void TreeNodeSelected(object selectedNode)
{
    var node = (FolderTreeNode)selectedNode;
    if (!node.IsFolder)
    {
        HandleTest(node);
        return;
    }
    HandleFolderNode(node);
}
```

This is a test node so we go to `HandleTest`:

```
    // puts null/"" in all the fields:
    CurrentTestInfo.Clear();
    // locate the node in the currentData table
    DataRow currentRow = null;
    foreach (DataRow dataRow in currentData.Rows)
    {
        if (dataRow["TestID"].ToString().Equals(string.Empty)) continue;
        if (node.TestId == Guid.Parse(dataRow["TestID"].ToString()))
        {
            currentRow = dataRow;
            break;
         }
     }
     CurrentTestInfo.TestName = currentRow["TestName"].ToString();
     CurrentTestInfo.Owner = currentRow["TestOwner"].ToString();
     CurrentTestInfo.LastUpdated = DateTime.Parse(currentRow["TestDate"].ToString());
```

TestInfo class:

```
public class TestInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string testName;
        public string TestName
        {
            get { return testName; }
            set
            {
                testName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TestName"));
            }
        }

        private DateTime? lastUpdated;
        public DateTime? LastUpdated
        {
            get { return lastUpdated; }
            set
            {
                lastUpdated = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("LastUpdated"));
            }
        }

        private string owner;
        public string Owner
        {
            get { return owner; }
            set 
            {
                owner = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Owner"));
            }
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            TestName = string.Empty;
            Owner = string.Empty;
            LastUpdated = null;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: The binding should definitely be `{Binding CurrentTestInfo.TestName}` as there is no element named `CurrentTestInfo`.

Comment: is CurrentTestInfo a direct property of TreeExplorerViewModel..? is it possible to show how you have declared it in viewmodel..?
and also try calling InitializeComponent(); before setting datacontext

Comment: I'm assuming you have changed your Binding back to: Text="{Binding Path=CurrentTestInfo.TestName}"

Comment: could you add the definition and assignment of the CurrentTestInfo property?

Comment: I've added it in the code above at the end of the code section before last. 
The thing is, in my `OnPropertyChanged` method, the `PropertyChanged` event is always null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your view model and `TestInfo` type implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)? Are you invoking the `PropertyChanged` event when the `CurrentTestInfo` and `TestName` properties are set?

Comment: I did forget that, but now that it's added, the binding is still not working - in my `OnPropertyChanged` method, when I check `PropertyChanged` for null, it **is** null and I think the event might not be raised. But if the binding is via XAML, shouldn't it seem null in the code?

Comment: Can you include your view model code, and also where the DataContext is set in the view's codebehind.

Comment: Try moving InitializeComponent(); to the top of the constructor. Also what type is CurrentTestInfo? Can you include the code for that, and your TreeExplorerViewModel view model?

Comment: Moving the `InitializeComponent();` doesn't change anything. `CurrentTestInfo` is of type `TestInfo`: `public TestInfo CurrentTestInfo;`. I'll update the relevant parts of the viewmodel.

Comment: At the end the issue was not calling `OnPropertyChanged()` for the `CurrentTestInfo` property. Shame on me and thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

In your binding, 'ElementName' is used when you want to bind to a XAML element's property. For example, if you were binding to another TextBox's Text property.

Change you binding back to:

```
Text="{Binding Path=CurrentTestInfo.TestName}"
```

Also, verify your ViewModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged. Your ViewModel needs to be raising the PropertyChanged event so that UI controls know to refresh themselves.

Comment: Changed it, added the `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation, but still no good - in my `OnPropertyChanged method`, when I check `PropertyChanged` for null, it is null and I think the event might not be raised.

Comment: Will you post the code for the CurrentTestInfo property as well as the TestName property?

Comment: Also make sure your setting the DataContext after InitializeComponent().